# Filtering List for "created by" of currently displayed user

Tags: list, my-site, filter

Hey i'm trying to filter a list for the currently displayed user in the mysites.

There is a list "projects" with all projects in it. If i navigate to some co-workers profile in the mysites he has a tab called "my projects" inside this tab i want to see every list item of the list "projects" which he has created.

I tried the out-of-the-box user context filter in various ways but i'm only receiving data which is connected to the currently logged in user.

I started a custom web part filter with the ITransformableFilterValues interface but im having problems writing it since i don't get how to pass the parameter from this filter webpart to the needed list.

If anybody could help me with the concept of this interface or propose some other solutions i'd be very glad!

Answer (score 1):

The first point to make is that this fields internal name is "Author" and that is a big point. The next part is if your Mysites are on the same domain/site. You may have issues with this. Then the user who is viewing the profile would need to have read access to the data you are trying to display. I imagine that you could do this with code or a webservice but I do not think you could with an out of box webpart. In my position I would use jQuery and Webservices to try this but that might not be feasible for you and I could understand that.